# What is rendering model in WinUi 3?

Tags: winui, winui-3

I want to create lightweight custom control, which will only render its content in specific way (without any additional logic like mouse/key handling etc). I think that it will be derived from Control class. But Win Ui's rendering model is too vague for me. I did not find any mention about overriding appearance of any controls. I used `IlSpy` program to analize win ui dlls. It shows nothing about rendering logic within such controls like `Button`, `Canvas`, `Control`, `FrameworkElement`, `UiElement`. It seems like I missed very important point about `WinUi`.

P.S. Other gui frameworks explicitly provide such feature. For example `WPF` actively uses `Visual` objects for such purposes. You can easily render to them.

Comment: The principles are the same as for UWP https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/composition/visual-layer (replace Windows.* namespace by Microsoft.* namespace) but more cross-platform oriented. In general, you don't need to "override rendering", as you're supposed to *compose* your objects and let the system do the final render. Check out the Microsoft.UI.Composition APIs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/ otherwise, you have DirectX interop:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop (SwapChainPanel, etc.) for low level rendering

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, it seems like the key. Structure of classes is almost the same in WinUI. As I understand WinUI uses UWP under the hood?

Comment: WinUI 3 is very different from WinUI 2. WinUI 2 is sort of an addon to UWP. WinUI 3 is a brand new framework, it's UI is based on WinRT (the new Windows API projectable over multiple langages, C++, C#, Rust, etc.) https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html